# How to reverse the OPENJSON() function in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, json

The sql-server OPENJSON() function can take a json array and convert it into sql table with key-value pairs, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = '{
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "key3": "val3"
    }';

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$')
```

Result:

```
key     value   type
--------------------
key1    val1    1
key2    val2    1
key3    val3    1
```

*What is the best **general-purpose method** for converting this key/value table back into a json array?*

Why? If we can do this with a single function, it opens up a range of json modifications which are otherwise not possible on sql server, e.g.:

- Re-order elements
- Rename properties (key names)
- Split json array into smaller arrays / combine json arrays
- Compare json arrays (which key/value elements exists in both jsons? What are the differences?)
- Clean json (remove syntactical whitespace/newlines to compress it)

Now, I could start to do simple CONCAT('"',[key],'":"',[value]), then do a comma-list-aggregration. But if I want a code that is both easy to apply across my codebase and works for all data types, this is not a simple task. By looking at the [json format definition](http://json.org/), the conversion should take into account a) the 6 different data types, b) escape characters, c) SQL NULL/json null handling, d) what I may have overlooked I.e. at minimum, the below example should be supported:

```
DECLARE @test_json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @test_json = '{
    "myNull": null,
    "myString": "start_\\_\"_\/_\b_\f_\n_\r_\t_\u2600_stop",
    "myNumber": 3.14,
    "myBool": true,
    "myArray": ["1", 2],
    "myObject": {"key":"val"}
    }'
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@test_json, '$')
```

Result:

```
key         value                           type
------------------------------------------------
myNull      NULL                            0
myString    start_\_"_/___ _ _ _☀_stop      1
myNumber    3.14                            2
myBool      true                            3
myArray     ["1", 2]                        4
myObject    {"key":"val"}                   5
```

For the string-aggregation part, we have long suffered the 'FOR XML PATH'-pain. Luckily we have STRING_AGG() on SQL2017/AzureDB, and I will accept a solution depending on STRING_AGG().

Comment: The function should of course take in the parameters `(key nvarchar(4000), value nvarchar(max), type int)`, where [`type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql#return-value) is 0,...,5.

Comment: It's an old, but interesting question (+1). When I was in a simiilar situation, I used the following solution (of course, not as an UDF and based on the JSON in the question): `SELECT CONCAT('{', STRING_AGG(t.Pair, ',') ,'}') FROM (SELECT CONCAT('"', [key], '":', CASE WHEN [type] = 0 THEN 'null' WHEN [type] = 1 THEN CONCAT('"', STRING_ESCAPE([value], 'json'), '"') WHEN [type] = 2 THEN [value] WHEN [type] = 3 THEN [value] WHEN [type] = 4 THEN JSON_QUERY([value]) WHEN [type] = 5 THEN JSON_QUERY([value]) END) AS Pair FROM OPENJSON(@test_json, '$')) t`

Comment: @Zhorov I eventually also ended up writing custom functions with CASE. Feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use string_agg

```
declare @json table ( Name varchar(80), Value varchar(max) )

insert into @json 
    select [Key], Value from openjson(@attributes)

insert into @json values ( 'name', @name )
insert into @json values ( 'title', @title )
insert into @json values ( 'description', @description )

set @attributes = '{' + (select STRING_AGG( '"' + Name + '":"' + 
    REPLACE (value, '"', '\"' ) +'"', ',') from @json) + '}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with this command, using [FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server)

```
select * from table for json auto
```

[image]

My result:

> [{"LogId":1,"DtLog":"2017-09-30T21:04:45.6700000","FileId":1},
>   {"LogId":2,"DtLog":"2017-09-30T21:08:35.8633333","FileId":3},{"LogId":3,"DtLog":"2017-09-30T21:08:36.4433333","FileId":2},{"LogId":4,"DtLog":"2017-09-30T21:08:36.9866667","FileId":12},{"LogId":5,"DtLog":"2017-09-30T21:15:22.5366667","FileId":13},{"LogId":6,"DtLog":"2017-09-30T21:38:43.7866667","FileId":17}]

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work. Mainly because the 'value' fields all will be converted back as a text. You are not able to take the 'type' into account.